# Google Charts NumberFormat "suffix" not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I was trying to add a suffix to the end of the information that is shown when you hover over one of the bars. Right now I'm displaying time usage in a shift of work, and wanted to display ' Hours' after the value on each bar.

I'm using

```
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ fractionDigits: 2, suffix: ' Hours' });
```

Any suffix I add will cause nothing to be rendered on the graph. The graph displays normally, but there are no bars on it.

If I remove the suffix from that formatter, and refresh, everything is displayed fine.

I'm using `Number(formatter.formatValue(thing[0].Ts.TotalHours))` to add the values.

Edit: It would also work if I could simply set the data type of the vAxis to 'Hours' so that the data is automatically displayed with ' Hours' after each value (if that is possible)

I should also note that when nothing is displayed on the graph, there are no errors in Javascript

Comment: Are you using exactly `Number(formatter.formatValue(thing[0].Ts.TotalHours))` to add this format to your numbers? This looks weird to me, I've used formats in the format `formatter.formatValue(thing[0].Ts.TotalHours)`. Also, as usual, a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) would easen for everybody else when we try to help you.

Comment: I'm using 'Number' as well because the data is coming in as Strings. The formatting works, as in it correctly formats the numbers to 2 decimal places. It is only when I specify a 'suffix' parameter that it causes no data to render on the graph.

Comment: Do you input your data as string, and then convert it to a number, while the data still expects a string? Sorry i'm not following you. Could you please set up a jsfiddle?